# Brute Force Security - Time of login

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, brute-force

In my application I'm adding reCaptcha but I also want to have a second method to prevent brute force attacks. After some researches, I thought in a solution that would block the user that is trying to log in if the attempt was made in a period of one second. For example, the user enters in the page and put their credentials and then press enter to attempt to log in; if that happened in a period of one second, I would block the user because that's not humanly possible (even if their credentials are saved in the browser).

But then the problem with that is that I'm counting the time in the javascript layer after the page is finished loading, so this solution is obviously easy to be hacked. I thought using the database, but that seems to be not reliable in terms of time (because of the request). So, what could I do to implement the best solution in this situation?

Comment: I would use both client and server side blocking. Client side e.g. is that I disable the login button or something and alert the user what happened. On the server side it also required because as you mentioned client side validation can be hacked. In these scenarios time is not a critical factor, so in my opinion the request time is unimportant. Moreover if too much request fall into the server from the same ip, that it is probably a flood attack, so you can reject those requests after a while (e.g. 10 failed captcha within 1 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like you want to "throttle" how fast login attempts can be made. This can be accomplished with a server generated "token" of some type

- When the token is generated at page request, store the time.
- Send the token to the login page.
- When the login request comes back make sure it has the token.
- Compare the time of login request to token generation time and if it's too soon deny the request in whatever way you see fit.
- Store each login attempt and if they are sent too close together deny them.